# Как правильно составить POST запрос?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, requests, postman

Пытаюсь составить POST запрос следующим образом, но в ответ получаю 404.

```py
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "Content-Length": "0",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "Origin": "http://httpbin.org",
    "Referer": "http://httpbin.org/",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5efa3c7e-e7789987e90d5b987cec5552"}

url = 'https://carte.by/auth/'
data = {'ajax':'register','login':'test5', 'pass':'test5', 'phone':'12345678', 'company':0, 'resend':1}
a = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

Тем не менее, такой же запрос в `postman` проходит. Подозреваю, что неправильно дату передаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но ведь не такой же, в postman вы явно выбрали form-data вместо json

Comment: Причём в реальности на сайте используется вообще x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: а, точно. А в каком формате тогда мне нужно сделать переменную `data`? И как передать в запрос? `requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=data)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй все тоже самое, но без headers - у меня работает:

```
import requests
url = 'https://carte.by/auth/'
data = {'ajax':'register','login':'test5', 'pass':'test5', 'phone':'12345678', 'company':0, 'resend':1}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.json)
```

В результате ответ 200:

```
200
{'error': 1, 'message': 'Логин занят. Укажите другой.'}
```

Осталось только указать другой логин...

Comment: ошибку запроса возвращает

Comment: Попробуй еще раз, я в коде ошибку допустил (надо data указывать, а не json), теперь поправил. Было `r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)`, теперь `r = requests.post(url, data=data)`. Должно работать

Comment: да, работает, спасибо. А почему с headers не хочет?

Comment: Не знаю, что-то ему там не нравится, но если полазить в headers, поубирать что-нибудь, то сработает.